# Statefulset's replica scheduling questions

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

Is there anyway I can tell Kuberbetes how to schedule the replicas in the statefulset? For example, I have nodes divided into 3 different availability zones (AZ). I have labeled these nodes accordingly. Now I want K8s to put 1 replica in each AZ based on node label. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pods will always try to be scheduled across different nodes, to achieve what you are looking for you can try to use `DaemonSet`, which will allow only one of these kind of pods in each node.

Also, you can use anti affinity based on the already scheduled pods in that node.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is called [Pod Anti-Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) and can be specified as such:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
[..]
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity: {}
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app: myapp
              topologyKey: az
            weight: 100
[..]
```

Since Kubernetes 1.18, there is also [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/), which is a nicer way to specify these anti-affinity rules.